Limit of function $\frac{\sin^2(x) - \tan^2(x)}{x^n}$ as $x \to0$
The problem is to find $n$ such that:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2(x) - \tan^2(x)}{x^n}
$$
is a non-zero real number.
My attempt:
The limit is of the type $\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]$. By using L'Hospital Rule four times I got:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2(x) - \tan^2(x)}{x^n} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-8\cos(2x) - 8\left(\frac{2\cos^2(x) + 3\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) + 15\sin^2(x)}{\cos^6(x)}\right)}{n\cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-3)\cdot x^{n-4}}
$$
Now for $x = 0$ the numerator is equal to $-24$. Thus if $n \neq 4$ then the limit does not satisfy desired properties. Now plugging $n = 4$ gives us the value of the limit to be $-1$, so the value of $n$ is $1$.
This question however appeared in my book before the concept of L'Hospital Rule and I wonder how to solve it without it. The book suggests to present the fraction in form:
$$
(\text{something with limit} \neq 0) \times \frac{1}{x^{n-4}}
$$
but I didn't manage to achieve this.

Perhaps they use the maclaurin series expansion on the numerator?

This is not a limit of a sequence.

Do you know that $\sin(x)/x\to1$ and $(1-\cos^2(x))/(x^2\to1$, as $x\to0$? If so, you can write it as $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{x^2}\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\frac{x^2\cdot(-1)\cdot x^2}{x^n}$

We can write $$\frac{\sin^2(x) - \tan^2(x)}{x^n}=\sin^2(x)\frac{\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\right) }{x^n}=\sin^2(x)\frac{\cos^2(x)-1}{x^n\cos^2(x)}$$
Using that $$\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}=1, \quad \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{\cos^2(t)-1}{-t^2}=1$$
we can replace $\sin^2(x)$ by $x^2$ and $\cos^2(x)-1$ by $-x^2$.
Therefore, the limit will the same as that of $$\dfrac{-x^4}{x^n\cos^2(x)}$$
Given that $\cos(x)\to 1$ when $x\to 0$, the limit will be finite iff $n\leq4$, and non-zero only when $n=4$; in that case, the limit will be $-1$.

Let $$f(x):=\frac{\sin^2x- \tan^2x}{x^n}.$$ Follow the suggestion of your book, which was to check that (as $x\to0$) $x^{n-4}f(x)$ has a non-zero (and finite) limit:
$$x^{n-4}f(x)=-\frac1{\cos^2x}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^4\to-\frac1{\cos^20}\left(1\right)^4=-1.
$$
